# Testing controller init process in Angular unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

Is it possible to test the init process of Angular controller?

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('led', []);
app.controller('zeppelin', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.love = function () {
        return 2;
    };

    $scope.tangerine = $scope.love();
    $scope.prove = function () {
        $scope.love();
    };

    $scope.prove();
    $scope.love();
}]);
```

Test code:

```
scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
controller = _$controller_('zeppelin', {
    $scope: scope
});

proved = sinon.spy();
loved = sinon.stub().returns(7);
scope.prove = proved;
scope.love = loved;
expect(proved.callCount).toBe(1); //=> 0
expect(loved.callCount).toBe(2); //=> 0
scope.prove();
expect(proved.callCount).toBe(2); //=> 1
expect(loved.callCount).toBe(3); //=> 0
```

My issues with the above code are:

1. I understand that expectation will fail as the controller is already initialized. If I set **scope.prove = spied** before the initialization, then I receive 0 for both, even after calling them explicitly. Is there a working approach for testing the init process?
2. How can I stub **scope.love**, so **scope.tangerine** receives the data from the stub, not from the controller?
3. Why after calling **scope.prove()**, **loved.callCount** does not increment?

To me the most curios case is **3** as I cannot think of any logical explanation for this strange behaviour.

Comment: For case 3 - When the controller gets initialized `$scope.prove` holds a reference to the anonymous function `function () {
    $scope.love();
}` That is getting replaced with the spy function returned by `sinon.spy` and that is an empty function that does not call `$scope.loved`. you should wrap the existing one in a spy instead of creating a new spy. Ej. `sinon.spy($scope, 'prove');`

Comment: Thanks! It seems I didn't set properly the spies functions, as I thought that both syntax are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

The controller is just a constructor which accepts the `$scope` object as an argument. You are defining functions on the scope

```
$scope.love = function () {
    return 2;
};
$scope.prove = function () {
    $scope.love();
};
```

and then immediately invoking them

```
$scope.prove();
$scope.love();
```

There is no way to intercept this process (in Angular, or in general) to spy on the functions before they are first called at the end of your controller. If you set `$scope.prove = spied` **before** initializing the controller, then it will simply be overwritten by the controller, if you set it **after** then the spies will not yet exist when the functions are called.

**2.**

For the reason described above, you cannot stub `$scope.love` in time for its return value to be assigned to `$scope.tangerine`. If it is truly important for you to be able to modify controller initialization behavior in tests, you should make `love` and injectable service inject it into the controller, and mock it in your tests.

**3.**

`$scope.prove` is overwritten by your spy (`scope.prove = proved`). You are losing the original function created in your controller which calls `$scope.love`. Instead, you need to spy on the existing function. For example,

```
var controller = $controller('zeppelin', { $scope: scope });

// here, the controller has initialized scope.prove and scope.love
var loved = sinon.spy(scope, 'love');
var proved = sinon.spy(scope, 'prove');

scope.prove();

// both callCounts are incremented
expect(proved.callCount).toBe(1);
expect(loved.callCount).toBe(1);
```

Comment: Much obliged, mate! I didn't expect(receivingAnswer()).toBeSuperTruthy()  :)

Answer (score 0):

As it appears it is impossible only for **scope** to be tested on the init process of the controller. Any other dependency can be tested, as it is beforehand known what their status.

Some code for confirmation:

```
app.controller('zeppelin', ['$scope','hangman', function ($scope, hangman) {
$scope.love = function () {
    hangman.a(4,6);
    return 'sweet';
};
$scope.tangerine = $scope.love();
$scope.prove = function () {
    $scope.love();
    hangman.a(4,$scope.tangerine);
};
hangman.a(4,6);
}]);
```

Test code:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _hangman_) {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    hangman = _hangman_;
    blackDog = sinon.spy(hangman, 'a');
    loved = sinon.spy(scope, 'love');
    controller = _$controller_('zeppelin', {
        $scope: scope,
        hangman: hangman
    });
    proved = sinon.spy(scope, 'prove');
}));
it('should x', function () {
    scope.prove();
    scope.love();
    expect(scope.tangerine).toBe('sweet');
    expect(loved.callCount).toBe(2);
    expect(blackDog.callCount).toBe(5);
    expect(proved.callCount).toBe(1);
});
```